# How to access a struct via an ArrayList in Java

Tags: java, arrays, arraylist

I have following lines of code:

```
private ArrayList<wordClass>[] words;
```

and

```
public class wordClass {
  public String wordValue = null;
  public int val = 0;
  public boolean used = false;  
}
```

Is there anyway I can access `wordValue`, `val`, and `used` via words? Like `words[5].val`? I know I can do that if they are just in an array of `wordClass`, but I want a dynamic array to make it easier to add and subtract from the array.

And yes, I know the values should be `private`. Just don't want to write getters and setters yet.

Thanks.

Comment: Well, they're public... - BTW, check what tags are for, and your terminology, before using them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you really want an Array of an ArrayList?
It doesn't seem correct.

In `Array`s, you use `[]` to access (`words[0]`).
In `ArrayList`s, you should use `words.get(0)`.
The way you have coded, you should use: `words[0].get(0).val` to get the very first value.

But I recommend you to review your `words` definition.

ArrayList Documentation: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html

Regards,
Bruno

Comment: Thanks. Didn't utilize "get". I'll accept your answer in 9 minutes.

Answer (score 0):

Your code is a bit off for a *dynamic array* (Java has immutable arrays), so you need an ArrayList. Also, Java uses Capital Letters for class names (please follow the convention) -

```
// like this, changing wordClass to WordClass. Also, using the diamond operator
private ArrayList<WordClass> words = new ArrayList<>();
```

To access your `WordClass` fields you can use something like -

```
for (WordClass wc : words) {
  if (wc.used) {
    System.out.println(wc.wordValue + " = " + wc.val);
  }
}
```

Note, you still need to create WordClass instances and place them into the words `List`.

Answer (score 0):

Write wrapper classes for each value. e.g. What you call "getters".

Then call:

```
    words[1].getWordValue()  ==> None
```

Voila

Comment: You're breaking Java naming convention there.

Comment: I've been using snake case for work forever, so I forgot the correct casing. My bad.